# onMessage not called in android GCMIntentService

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

i have to implement a code for push notifications. when i sent details from server it wont be get into the mobile. here onMessgae() method not called when i push the details from server. please tell me what was the issue.

Here is my code

```
GCMIntentService.java

private static final String TAG = "srinu";
    public static final String SENDER_ID = "834017698652";
    public static final String DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION = "com.hilo.goldbutton.Home";
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String PUSH_TOKEN_SERVICE = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    public static final String READ_TOKEN_SERVICE = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    Context ctx;

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(GCMIntentService.SENDER_ID);
         try {  
                       Class.forName("android.os.AsyncTask");  
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {  
        }  
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, final String registrationId) {

        mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                final String tmDevice, tmSerial, androidId;
                tmDevice = "" + tm.getDeviceId();
                tmSerial = "" + tm.getSimSerialNumber();
                androidId = "" + android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
                UUID deviceUuid = new UUID(androidId.hashCode(), ((long)tmDevice.hashCode() << 32) | tmSerial.hashCode());
                String deviceId = deviceUuid.toString();
                String responsePushToken=Helper.getSourceCode(PUSH_TOKEN_SERVICE+"token="+deviceId+"&email="+RegistrationActivity.mail);

                Log.v("srinu", "-----respushtoken:"+responsePushToken);

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                mRegisterTask = null;
            }
        };
        mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.v("srinu", "Device unregistered");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onMessage(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
                Log.v("srinu", "--------------------------------------------------" + intent.getExtras().getString("message"));
                ctx = context;
                String other_key = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
                generateNotification(context, other_key);
                handleMessage(intent,other_key);

      }


    @Override
    protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
        }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        Intent notificationIntent;
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
            notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Notifications.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title + " sent you a message",
                message, intent);
        notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

    }
     private void handleMessage( Intent intent,final String message)
        {
           // final String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");

          Thread t = new Thread()
            {

                public void run()
                {

                    Message myMessage = new Message();
                    Bundle resBundle = new Bundle();
                    resBundle.putString( "message", message );
                    myMessage.setData( resBundle );
                    handler.sendMessage( myMessage );
                }
            };
            t.start();
         }

        private Handler handler = new Handler()
        {

              public void handleMessage( Message msg )
                    {

                     Toast.makeText( getBaseContext(), msg.getData().getString( "message" ), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    }
        };

}


Home.java:

public class Home extends Activity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
         try {  
                 Class.forName("android.os.AsyncTask");  
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {  
        } 
        gcm(this);
    }
private void gcm(final Context context) {
        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(context);
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(context);

        registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                GCMIntentService.DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));
        if (Helper.RegistrationId.equals("empty")) {
            GCMRegistrar.register(context, GCMIntentService.SENDER_ID);
        } else {
            if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(context)) {
                Log.v("srinu", "GCM Display Message : "
                        + "Already registered");

            }
        }
    }
    private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(
                    GCMIntentService.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            Log.d("Reva", "GCM Display Message : " + newMessage);
        }
    };
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR_MR1
                && !isKindleFire()) {
            if (mRegisterTask != null)
                mRegisterTask.cancel(true);
            unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);
            GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);
        }
    }
    public static boolean isKindleFire() {
        return android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER.equals("Amazon")
                && (android.os.Build.MODEL.equals("Kindle Fire") || android.os.Build.MODEL
                        .startsWith("KF"));
    }
}

manifest.xml

 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


 <permission
        android:name="com.hilo.goldbutton.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.hilo.goldbutton.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.hilo.goldbutton.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.hilo.goldbutton.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_lanucher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.hilo.goldbutton" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
         <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" /> 
         <activity
            android:name="com.hilo.goldbutton.Home"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>
```

Comment: any one can help me please.

Comment: Can you post your Android XML to verify if you add the correct permission, the receiver and service!